# Can you recommend an Application Framework for Windows Forms?

Tags: .net, winforms

Do you know some higher level Framework Library which sits on top of Windows Forms?

Tasks:

- Command Management
- Master/Detail Form Management
- Record Navigation
- Input Validation

etc.

Of course, I could do this all by myself but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

(sorry for my broken english!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at the Smart Client Software Factory from Microsoft Patterns and practices; this provides quite a rich (but complex) framework for managing views within WinForms applications.

You may also want to look at one of the many third-party widows forms component vendors for some rich controls (Telerik, Infragistics etc).

CSLA is a good business object framework that supports winforms applications very well.

I currently work on a WinForms application built on the SCSF with CSLA; it's a steep learning curve but has produced a successful appllication wich the users like and is reasonably easy to maintain and enhance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [DevExpress eXpressApp framework](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Application_Framework/)
I never had the chance to use it in production, but the demos and quick tests were very promising.

We used [Enterprise Library](http://www.codeplex.com/entlib) (and own solution) for Validation and Data Access
An own solution for Master/Detail Form Management and [Composite UI Application Bloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480450.aspx)k (CAB) for Command Management (kind of)

Comment: I can definitely see how Enterprise Library validation Block and the CAB could be useful to johasoft123.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not especially strong in the particular areas you cite, CSLA is a good framework, and the associated book [Expert C# 2008 Business Objects by Rockford Lhotka](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210192) is a good book to help you think of app arch in general (even if I didnt end up using it or 100% agreeing with every stance taken, it was still worth the time).

Answer (score 0):

I think MX-Frame covers features you described.

www.mxframe.net